# C# static implicit operator to easily convert a single object of type T into a new List<T>

Tags: c#

Consider the following:

```
public class DataPacket
{
    public DataPacket(string name) { /* ... */ }

    public static implicit operator List<DataPacket>(DataPacket data) {
        return new List<DataPacket> { data };
    }
}
```

Is it always safe to handle any single DataPacket as if it was a List (if I don't mind the new instantiation)?

---

Here's a little bit of context:

I have a class that is usually bundled into Lists for all the pipelines handling that class. But sometimes a want to shovel just a single new object into one of these pipelines.

To make this smoother I'm using the implicit operator. Here's a code example:

```
public void Pipline(List<DataPacket> packets)
{
    // ... do stuff with packets
}

public void Main()
{
    // Pipleine A and B
    Pipline(new List<DataPacket>
    {
        new DataPacket("A"),
        new DataPacket("B"),
    });

    // Pipline only C
    Pipline(new DataPacket("C"));
}
```

Comment: Please read here if you want to ask for a code review: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1689#1689

Comment: You could also achieve this without an implicit conversion parameter by defining `public void Pipeline(params DataPacket[] packets) {…}` and then call it with `Pipeline(new DataPacket("A"), new DataPacket("B"));`.

Comment: Why not write another overload of `Pipeline` that takes a `DataPacket`?

Comment: I'm aware there are many possible routes I can take here. The DataPackets are stored and handled as Lists in multiple places in code, so it makes sense to me to want them to (almost) always be wrapped inside a list. Basically the answer I'm looking for is either: "Yes, I've used this kind of List instantiation, works fine" or "No, you will run into this problem: ..."

Comment: This just does not seem right. You are going to face the same difficulties again and again during development with this design. Since you are not converting between different data types but a data type and an array of the same type. And there is already a solution for that mentioned in previous comments. Operators are for different purpose.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen: "You are going to face the same difficulties again and again during development with this design." - would you care to elaborate? "the same difficulties" as what? It seems currently, the "difficulty" perceived by the OP is that they do not want to define additional overloads of all the various methods that accept a `List<DataPacket>`, and that difficulty is indeed removed once and for all with the shown design (possibly *other* difficulties notwithstanding).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Yes, you are right. Maybe not. I was wrong sorry about that.